# SQL SERVER 2008 - Select query OPEN ROWSET

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, vb6, openrowset

I have a select statement where I'm pulling data from Database1 that looks something like this...

```
g_SQL = "SELECT 'ID' = companyID, 'Name' = (CompanyName + CompanyAddress)
g_SQL = " FROM tblCompanies WHERE CompanyStatus='InBusiness'"
```

Now what I need to do is go into another database and select data from tblCompanyinventory, Database2 where I need to do a...

```
sum(inventory) for each CompanyID
```

And then I'd want it to be displayed in the 'Name' like this 'Name'= (CompanyName + CompanyAddress + sum(inventory))

I will use the 2 fields: ID and NAME and I pass it on to a combobox loader. This is a vb6 application I'm working on.

Any ideas how I'd go about it? Open Rowset? I've never done anything of this nature before.

I have connections set for both - for Database1 it's g_CN1, and Database2 it is g_CN2 - as ADODB.Connection. These databases are on the same server.

Comment: Are the two databases on the same SQL instance?  if so, and your authentication model allows it then you can do a cross database join using the three part table name so select .. from Database1.dbo.tblCompanies Join Database2.dbo.tblCompanyInventory ON .... Is there a reason the tables are on two different databases?

Comment: Yes they are. Database2 serves as a inventory database for multiple applications (that's where everything gets inserted). Because inventory/companies get updated quite frequently, and all companyID's are hardcoded in the application we are trying to move it into another database, this way we don't have to update the code, we can just update the table and it will select the necessary companies.

Comment: Are you saying you don't have access to the SQL and connection strings for your Database 1? It's not in the same VB file? It's probably OpenRecordset you're looking for - but that should be in your existing code already - unless you're starting from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP's comments some SQL like this may be what is required.

```
g_SQL = "SELECT 'ID' = C.companyID, 'Name' = (CompanyName + CompanyAddress), I.InvSum "
g_SQL = g_SQL + " FROM Database1.dbo.tblCompanies C JOIN (SELECT SUM(inventory) As InvSum from"
g_SQL = g_SQL + "  Database2.dbo.tblCompanyInventory GROUP BY CompanyId) I "
g_SQL = g_SQL + " ON I.CompanyId = C.companyId WHERE CompanyStatus='InBusiness'"
```

without knowing how the connection is established I can't say whether there will be an authentication issue or not.

Comment: there is a password and username so I'll need to include those. I'm looking online and am finding something with OPENROWSET where I include the server name, Driver, Username, password. I'm not sure if this is correct

Comment: If the database is on the same SQL instance then the SQL login can be granted access to both Database1 and database2 and it can run from a single connection.